# Puppeteer: Can't click on input[type=radio]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, puppeteer

I'm trying to access a clickable input radio using Puppeteer to advance in my application's survey. Below are the selector and xpath tags.

Selector:

```
#survey-engine > span > div > div > div > div > div.col-xs-12.col-xl-offset-2.col-xl-8.col-lg-offset-1.col-lg-10 > div > div:nth-child(1) > input[type="radio"]
```

XPath:

```
//*[@id="survey-engine"]/span/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/input
```

I've been unable to get to the xpath or selector to work correctly. I've also tried using below but no luck. See error using selector:

```
>UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: No node found for selector: #survey-engine > span > div > div > div > div > div.col-xs-12.col-xl-offset-2.col-xl-8.col-lg-offset-1.col-lg-10 > div > div:nth-child(1) > input[type="radio"]
    at Console.assert (console.js:194:23)
    at Frame.click (/Users/erickloos/Desktop/phs-platform/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:597:13)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:48518) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:48518) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

```
(await page.$x("//input[contains(text(), 'My Input's Text')]"))[0];
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not simply try (assuming jquery is on page)?

```
var input = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return $('#survey-engine > span > div > ... > div:nth-child(1) > input[type="radio"]';
});
```

***Note*** I removed some of the selectors from your question for brevity...

Comment: I'll get this error.

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object Object]' is not a valid selector.


When using document.querySelector instead of $ I'll get this errror:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: No node found for selector: undefined

Comment: what happens if you type that selector inside chrome console?

Comment: I'll get this:

init [input, prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: "#survey-engine > span > div > div > div > div > di…10 > div > div:nth-child(1) > input[type="radio"]"]

Comment: When I use the first index which is the actual input in the console I'm getting this error when running my script. 

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#' is not a valid selector.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Was able to get it to work

await page.evaluate(() => {
     var test = document.querySelector('#survey-engine > span > div > div > div > div > div.col-xs-12.col-xl-offset-2.col-xl-8.col-lg-offset-1.col-lg-10 > div > div:nth-child(1) > input[type="radio"]')
     test.click();
    })

Comment: Good old vanilla javascript! Happy you tracked it down.

Answer (score 5):

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
       var test = document.querySelector('#survey-engine > span > div > div > div > div > div.col-xs-12.col-xl-offset-2.col-xl-8.col-lg-offset-1.col-lg-10 > div > div:nth-child(1) > input[type="radio"]')
        test.click();
    })
```